# Не работает функция get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress

В файле index.php

```
    $redux_demo = get_option('redux_demo');
//беру из redux тип главной страницы (проверял, в переменную данные заносятся правильно)
    $tmp=$redux_demo['type-page']; //здесь '1'
//вывожу из функции страницу
    get_posts_teml($tmp)
```

Файл functions.php

```
function get_posts_teml($tmp)
{
    switch ($tmp) {
        case '1':
             get_template_part('/assets/homepage-tmp', 'one-col');
            break;
        case '2':
             get_template_part("/assets/homepage-tmp", 'two-col');
            break;
        case '3':
            get_template_part("/assets/homepage-tmp", 'one-col-without-sidebar');
            break;
    };
}
```

файл one-col.php

```
<?php echo 2?>
```

При этом ничего не выводится. Через функцию `include_once` всё работает.

```
include_once('/assets/homepage-tmp/one-col.php')
```

Расположение файлов

```
index.php
assets
  homepage-tmp
    one-col.php
```

Comment: а если так(убрать слеш) get_template_part('assets/homepage-tmp', 'one-col');

Comment: нет, не помогло. Все эти проблемы начались после того как я загрузил unit test для проверки темы.

Comment: посмотрите (или покажите) ошибки в консоли и лог, может немного прояснится ситуация.

Comment: ошибка какаета выходит? включите показ ошибок в php

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в `get_template_part("/assets/homepage-tmp", 'two-col');`

Надо без слеша:

`get_template_part("assets/homepage-tmp", 'two-col');`

И это подключит файл `assets/homepage-tmp-two-col.php` из каталога активной темы.